# How to add a space between consecutive letters and numbers in PySpark dataframe?

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, regexp-replace

I have a dataframe which consists of text columns. There are some words which has numbers as well which are followed by words. I want to separate the numbers and words and add a space between them.

For example:

```
Machine1234 -> Machine 1234
5years -> 5 years
```

Below is my dataframe

```
+---+--------------------------------------------+
|id |words                                       |
+---+--------------------------------------------+
|0  |This is Spark123 of 5years                  |
|1  |I wish Java DL1234 could use case classes444|
|2  |Data science is  cool321                    |
|3  |Machine345                                  |
+---+--------------------------------------------+
```

Below is the code I used but it is not working

```py
df2 = temp.select('id',
    F.regexp_replace('words', r'(\d+(\.\d+)?)', ' \1').alias('words'))
```

Desired output:

```
+---+----------------------------------------------+
|id |words                                         |
+---+----------------------------------------------+
|0  |This is Spark 123 of 5 years                  |
|1  |I wish Java DL 1234 could use case classes 444|
|2  |Data science is  cool 321                     |
|3  |Machine 345                                   |
+---+----------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
F.regexp_replace('words', r'(\p{L}+)(\d+)', '$1 $2')
```

<sup>`\p{L}` matches only letters</sup>

Full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(0, 'This is Spark123'),
     (1, 'I wish Java DL1234 could use case classes444'),
     (2, 'Data science is  cool321'),
     (3, 'Machine345')],
    ['id', 'words'])

df = df.withColumn('words', F.regexp_replace('words', r'(\p{L}+)(\d+)', '$1 $2'))

df.show(truncate=0)
# +---+----------------------------------------------+
# |id |words                                         |
# +---+----------------------------------------------+
# |0  |This is Spark 123                             |
# |1  |I wish Java DL 1234 could use case classes 444|
# |2  |Data science is  cool 321                     |
# |3  |Machine 345                                   |
# +---+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi . If the number is at the beginning of the word, then it is not working. I have updated the question. For example, "5years -> 5 years". Can you please check?

Comment: Got it. We just has to reverse: F.regexp_replace('words', r'(\d+)(\p{L}+)', '$1 $2')

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace,col
# Assume data present in dataframe named df
df.withColumn("words", regexp_replace(col('words'),'(\D*)(\d+)','$1 $2')).show(truncate=False)

+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|id |words                                                      |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|0  |This is Spark 123                               |
|1  |I wish Java DL 1234 could use case classes 444             |
|2  |Data science is  cool 321                                  |
|3  |Machine 345                                                |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```